# Run a full node with multiple IP addresses

Tags: full-node, network

I run a full Bitcoin node on a powerful server however rather than setting up multiple I was wondering if it's possible to use multiple IP addresses on one installation and one running process? Without people being able to detect it's the same node (not easily anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can allocate multiple IP addresses to one machine (hint: you can), then yes, you can have one node bound to multiple IP addresses and serving peers on all of them. It's impossible to tell whether two nodes you are connected to are actually the same node so that doesn't matter. Note that doing this does not help the network any more than having one IP address and one node.

Comment: Why doesn't it help? Whats the difference between one node with 5 IPs vs 5 nodes with 1 IP each. In terms of helping spread the blockchain and signalling no 2x

Comment: If your node goes down, all of the nodes connected to your 5 IPs lose a connection, and that could be many nodes. If there are 5 nodes and one goes down, then only the nodes connected to that one IP address lose a connection. More nodes adds more robustness to the network and is generally better.

Comment: Well I only have one server so the other option would be to host multiple VMs which could cause the same problem and I guess running one node with 100+ connections spread across 5 VMs would use more resources than having 1 node with 100 connections active. How do I bind multiple IPs to the node?